# Search not working in SharePoint 2013 for users from a Trusted Login Providers (STS)

Tags: security, search, sharepoint-2013, claims-based-identity

Via this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955607(v=office.14).aspx, I have created and implemented a functional custom security token service (STS). Everything looked peachy for a while, but then I started to run into errors different places in SharePoint (when logged in as a non-NT user). Follwing is failing and givind errors (but only for STS users):

**Search** (everything)

*Error on page:* 
Sorry, something went wrong.

Correlation ID: ee18209c-9e46-90f9-0e7f-e974c988e4a7

*SharePoint Log:*

Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.LinguisticQueryProcessingExecutor : QSC: All Annotations: ,
Microsoft.Ceres.ContentEngine.Processing.BuiltIn.ClaimsConverterProducer : **IdentityClaim from STS differs from known type: wb100o20onswg4lsnf1hs4dpnnsw332foj2gsy2forzhk32umvsdu2junfsha**
Component and System=Query1-bb91f516-fa71-45ed-b37b-3e93ab198c18, Correlation ID=ee18209c-9e46-90f9-0e7f-e974c988e4a7, Tenant ID=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Error code=, Flow Name=Microsoft.SharePointSearchProviderFlow, Operator Name=ParserExecutor, Message=The processing of item fails with error Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.FlowHandleRegistry : Exceptions occurred when evaluating the flow.  Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.DataModel.EvaluationException: Evaluation failed in operator IndexLookupExecutor of type IndexLookupExecutor ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.     at Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Processing.BuiltIn.SecurityPreFilterProducer.BuildOrNode(String[] acls, Boolean isDeny)     at Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Processing.BuiltIn.SecurityPreFilterProducer.AndNotWithTwoOrNodes(TreeNode treeNode, String[] acls, Boolean onlyFilterNode)     at Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Processing.BuiltIn.SecurityPreFilterProducer.AddSecurityFilter(TreeNode treeNode, String[] acls, Int32 allowAcls, Int32 denyAcls, String...
... tenantId)     at Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Processing.BuiltIn.SecurityPreFilterProducer.AddSecurityFilter(TreeNode treeNode, String docAclInput, String tenantId)     at Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Processing.BuiltIn.SecurityPreFilterProducer.ProcessRecordCore(IRecord record)     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Executor.ProducerOperatorExecutor`1.ProcessProducerRecord(IRecord inputRecord)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.IndexLookupExecutor.ExecuteCore(IRecord inputRecord)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Executors.QueryPipelineFlowExecutor.Execute(IRecord inputRecord)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Pipeline.Processing.ExecutorProducer`1.ProcessRecord(IRecord record)     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Proc...
...essing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord record)     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithoutTryCatch(IRecord record)     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.PushToOutput()     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord record)     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithoutTryCatch(IRecord record)     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.PushToOutput()     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord record)     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithoutTryCatch(IRecord record)     at Mi...
...crosoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.PushToOutput()     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord record)     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithoutTryCatch(IRecord record)     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.PushToOutput()     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord record)     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithoutTryCatch(IRecord record)     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.PushToOutput()     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Processing.Producers.ProducerRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord record)     at...
... Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.Aborting.AbortableRecordSetSink.Put(IRecord record)     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithTryCatch(IRecord record)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.Ceres.Evaluation.Engine.ErrorHandling.HandleExceptionRecordSetSink.DoWithTryCatch(IRecord record)     at Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.FlowHandleRegistry.SubmitData(FlowExecutionInfo handle, InputData inputData, Stopwatch timer, String correlationId, Guid tenantId, String query, String flowName, Int32 queryTimeoutMillis)     at Microsoft.Ceres.InteractionEngine.Component.FlowHandleRegistry.ExecuteFlow(String flowName, InputData input, Int32 queryTimeoutMillis)

**Other non-NT MySites** has error in the activity web part (looks like search Again). NT MySites look nice and pretty (well at least like SharePoint)

*Error on page:* 
Something went wrong - Technical Details - 
SharePoint returned the following error: The target of the operation was not found. Contact your system administrator for help in resolving this problem.

**#Topics (all)**

*Error on page:* 
Relevant conversations - Sorry, something went wrong.

Correlation ID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Been spending a some long days now, looking in all possible places in SharePoint and now starting to bang my head against the wall. From my point of view it looks like search and users rights/resolving is giving me a hard time here, but I cannot seems to get rid of the problems.

...so any help is much appreciated by now - thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To others that might be in this predicament, the answer is patience - at least until the June 2013 patch is released (only see the Foundation so far). The issues found in my initial post should be solved in this update accordingly to Microsoft Support... more will definitely show up in the world of SharePoint - go luck :)

**Update:**
Back from summer Holiday and getting up to speed with the Work done before - yes, it takes a while after 4 weeks :) Anyways, I did the patch (first in test env. ofc and then in production) and it actually seems to have fixed the issues that we were facing = happy me and very happy client. More testing and finalizing on MySites and user data next week.

A brief update - have a nice summer.
Rune